# Avoiding "Usage of a direct database call is discouraged"

Tags: wpdb, coding-standards

[WordPress-Coding-Standards](https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards) reports that *"Usage of a direct database call is discouraged."*

It's complaining about my usage of [`$wpdb->insert()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/) in a plugin. Is this not recommended? What is the correct way to insert data into a plugin's database table?

Or can I just ignore this error? In which case, is there some system to mark it as reviewed and not to be flagged again?

Comment: Can you post the code snippet that the sniff is being reported on? Also you can create a custom ruleset to negate this sniff under certain conditions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `$wpdb->insert` and or related methods to modify data within any of the default WordPress tables, be it **posts, postmeta, user, usermeta** etc is discouraged because there are functions which already exist for the purpose of modififying data within those tables.

For example,

- [`wp_insert_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)
- [`wp_update_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post)
- [`wp_delete_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_post)

### Database Queries

> Avoid touching the database directly. If there is a defined function that can get the data you need, use it. Database abstraction (using functions instead of queries) helps keep your code forward-compatible and, in cases where results are cached in memory, it can be many times faster.
>
> https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/#database-queries

However **it is acceptable** to use the [`wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) class on custom tables for which no function wrappers exist for the purpose in which you need.

You can try adding a comment on the line of the query:

```
$wpdb->insert() //db call ok
$wpdb->insert() //db call ok; no-cache ok
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, adding the comments fixes it. I assumed it must be okay to do direct DB access at *some* point. :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: The regex for this is `/db call\W*(ok|pass|clear|whitelist)/i`. See https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards/blob/06abcd4c2f20b754e72d609ab153fd4282b1b40b/WordPress/Sniffs/VIP/DirectDatabaseQuerySniff.php#L76